# Remove timestamp from GWT logger

Tags: java, gwt, logging

I'd like to remove the timestamp from GWT logging output on the console.

What's the simplest way to do this? Ideally, in the `.gwt.xml` configuration would be great.

Here is an example output currently with the timestamp:

```
Wed Mar 21 08:23:57 EDT 2012 Job 
FINE: Job: 'updater': end
```

**EDIT**: I am only interested in the client side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This logging capability is not really configurable. You need to write your own formatter:
call this at the beginning of onModuleLoad():

```
Handler[] handlers = Logger.getLogger("").getHandlers();
for(Handler h : handlers){
  h.setFormatter(new MyCustomLogFormatter());
}
```

And here is an example of a formatter:

```
public class MyCustomLogFormatter extends TextLogFormatter{
    private static DateTimeFormat timeFormat = DateTimeFormat.getFormat("HH:mm:ss.SSS");
    public MyCustomLogFormatter() {
        super(true);
    }

    @Override
    public String format(LogRecord event) {
        StringBuilder message = new StringBuilder();
        message.append(getRecordInfo(event, " "));
        message.append(event.getMessage());
        message.append(getStackTraceAsString(event.getThrown(), "\n", "\t"));
        return message.toString();
    }
    @Override
    protected String getRecordInfo(LogRecord event, String newline) {
        Date date = new Date(event.getMillis());
        StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
        s.append(timeFormat.format(date));
        s.append(" GWT ");
        s.append(event.getLevel().getName());
        String loggerName = event.getLoggerName();
        String[] split = loggerName.split("\\.");
        s.append(" ");
        s.append(split[split.length-1]);
        s.append(newline);
        s.append(": ");
        return s.toString();
      }
}
```

More: http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideLogging.html

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer shows how to customize GWT log messages. The example is longer than necessary, though. In case anyone wants to just remove the timestamp (the original question), here is a shorter snippet:

```
Handler[] handlers = Logger.getLogger("").getHandlers();

for (Handler h : handlers) {
    h.setFormatter(new TextLogFormatter(false) {

        @Override
        public String format(LogRecord event) {
            return event.getLoggerName() + ": " +
                    event.getLevel().getName() + ": " +
                    event.getMessage();
        }
    });
}
```

Watch out for the "gotcha" of doing this in the constructor of a singleton dependency-injected class---you want to make sure GWT has had the chance to actually add handlers to the logger first.

Answer (score -1):

It uses the same pattern config as log4j, see here: http://code.google.com/p/gwt-log/wiki/GettingStarted#Control_the_format_of_your_log_messages

In the gwt-log wiki it says:

> Server side logging automatically detects Apache log4j, falling back
>   to JDK 1.4 logging

As there is a "FINE" log level in your post, it should be the second case. Either include Log4J in your classpath or check "logging.properties" from your current jdr/jre-conf directory.

Comment: The compiler doesn't like the line `<set-configuration-property name="log_pattern" value="(%F:%L) %d [%-5p] %m%n" />`

Comment: Can you elaborate on "doesn't like" ? What is the error message it gives?

Comment: gwt-log is a different project, he is using built-in gwt logging features

Comment: "Built-in gwt logging" is using JDK Logging as well.